# How to generate HMAC-SHA-256 sign in javascript for datatrans?

Tags: javascript, angular, sha256, cryptojs

I have an Angular project in which I have to implement [datatrans](https://docs.datatrans.ch/) payment. But I am not able to generate sign for payment.

I am following process given on this link ([enter link description here](https://docs.datatrans.ch/docs/security-sign)) to generate sign.

But i am not able to achive it.

I am using angular library crypto-js to generate HMAC-SHA-256 signed string.

Here is my javascript code.

```
const merchantId = 'xxxxxxx';
const refNo = '1234567890';
const amount = 0;
const currency = 'CHF';
const theme = 'DT2015';
const paymentmethod = 'VIS';

const stringSs = merchantId+amount+currency+refNo;

const base = 16;
// My Hmac Key
const s = 'fa3d0ea1772cf21e53158283e4f123ebf1eb1ccfb15619e2fc91ee6860a2e5e48409e902b610ce5dc6f7f77fab8affb60d69b2a7aa9acf56723d868d36ab3f32';

// Step 1: Code to generate hex to byte of hmac key
const a = s.replace(/../g, '$&_').slice (0, -1).split ('_').map ((x) => parseInt (x, base));

//  Step 3: Sign the string with HMAC-SHA-256 together with your HMAC key
const signedString = HmacSHA256(a, stringSs);

// Step 4: Translate the signature from byte to hex format
const signString = enc.Hex.stringify(signedString);
```

Can you help me into this to suggest what i am doing wrong or in what way it can be achieved.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with crypto (no need of extra libraries to install)

```
// Typescript
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

function signKey (clientKey: string, msg: string) {
    const key = new Buffer(clientKey, 'hex');
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(msg).digest('hex');
}
```

```
// Javascript
const crypto = require('crypto')

function signKey (clientKey, msg) {
    const key = new Buffer(clientKey, 'hex');
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', key).update(msg).digest('hex');
}
```

```
signKey(s, stringSs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question for crypto-js (see https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) as requested, the following will do the trick:

```js
// Javascript; example from datatrans documentation using a random key
stringSs ='3000017692850CHF91827364';
key='1ca12d7c0629194a9f9d0dbbc957709dd3aed385925b077e726813f0b452de6a38256abd1116138d21754cfb33964b6b1aaa375b74d3580fcda916898f553c92';
expectedSign='d7dee9ae1e542bc02bcb063a3dd3673871b2e43ccb4c230f26e8b85d14e25901';

signedString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringSs, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key));
resultSign = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(signedString);

// now resultSign == expectedSign is true :-)
```

Ninja Turtles approach was almost correct except of step 1, hex to byte. Use a builtin function of Crypto-JS instead and everything works as expected.